# weakly compactness and a minimization

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Suppose $S\subset L_1 $ is weakly compact with respect to weak topology.

$$g^*: S\to L_{\infty}$$

We have known for every $f\in S$, $g^*(f)\in A$.

Suppose $$\inf_{f\in S} F(f,g^*(f))$$

is not linear in $f$ and may not have a minimum in $S$.(I think weak  compactness cannot play any role here?)

Can I conclude that for the greatest lower bound $A^*=\inf_{f\in S} F(f,g^*(f))$,  we must have $g^*(f^*)\in A$?

To be more specific

$$g^*(f)=\chi_{E^*_1(f)}-\chi_{E^*_2(f)}$$

$$F(f,g^*(f))=\int_{E^*_1(f)}  (f'-f )d\mu -\int_{E^*_2(f)} ( f'-f )d\mu$$

where $E^*_1(f),E^*_2(f)$ are measurable sets and $f'\in L_1$ is a given parameter.

Comment: A lot of information is missing to answer your question: what are the properties of $A$, $S$, $g^*$, $F$?

Comment: $S$ is a convex and weakly compact subset of unit ball in $L^1$.  $g^*(f)$ is given by $sup_{g\in G} \int g (f'- f)  d\mu$ where $G$ is the unit ball in $L_{\infty}$ and $f'\in L_1$ is exogenously given. I knew that the maximizer $g^*(f) \in A$, where $A$ stands for the set of positive and negative  signed all indicator functions of measurable sets.

Comment: Now $F(f,g^*(f))=\int_{E^*_1(f)}  (f'-f )d\mu -\int_{E^*_2(f)} ( f'-f )d\mu$ . where $g^*(f)=\chi_{E^*_1(f)}-\chi_{E^*_2(f)}$.

Comment: Hi,do you have any suggestion on whether the problem is well defined?

Comment: How does $E_1^*$ depend on $f$?

Comment: I assume $-1\leq g\leq 1$,   by solving $\sup_{g} \int g(f'-f)d\mu$, if $f'-f>0$, then $g^*=1$,   if $f'-f=0$,   $g^*=0$ and if $f'-f<0$,  $g^*=-1$. Then $E^*_1(f)=\{x\in [0,1]: f'(x)-f(x)>0\} $and $E^*_2(f)=\{x\in [0,1]: f'(x)-f(x)<0\}$

Comment: In my humble opinion, due to a big number of objects, many relations between then, not very clear exposition, and possible misprints it is hard to grasp what is going on in this question.